# Deletion in Link List showing "0"

Tags: c++, linked-list

I cannot figure it out why am getting a 0 when trying to delete the first element of the list?
I have inserted 3 elements (7,8,9),when am deleting 8 or 9 its working fine for me ,but when am trying to delete 7(.i.e the first element) irrespective of the no of elements present in the list am only getting a val of 0,screenshot attached in the end.

This is how the code works

- Insert an element either at first position(press 1 for that ),for any
  other position press 2
- display the list
- delete the element from the list

Here is the code

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
        private:
        int info;
        class node *ptr;
        public:

        class node * insertNode(class node * head);
        void traverseList(class node * head);
        class node * deleteNode(class node * head);
};
class node * node::insertNode(class node * head){
    node * newNode=new node();
    node * curNode=new node();
    int position,srchPos=0;
    if(newNode==NULL)
        cout<<"Node Creation Failed"<<endl;
    else{
        cout<<"Enter data to be stored"<<endl;
        cin>>newNode->info;
        newNode->ptr=NULL;
        cout<<"To Add in First Position  Press 1 else 2\n";
        cin>>position;
        if(position==1){
                newNode->ptr=head;
                head=newNode;           
            }
        else{
                curNode=head;
                cout<<"Enter the data after which you want to insert\n";
                cin>>srchPos;
                while((curNode->info!=srchPos)&&(curNode->ptr!=NULL)){
                        curNode=curNode->ptr;
                }
                if(curNode==NULL){
                        cout<<"Data not Found"<<endl;               
                }
                else{
                        newNode->ptr=curNode->ptr;
                        curNode->ptr=newNode;
                }
        }
    }
        return head;
}
void node::traverseList(class node * head){
            node * curNode=new node();
            curNode=head;
            cout<<"Data Present in the List ::\n";
            while(curNode!=NULL){
            cout<<curNode->info<<"\t";
            curNode=curNode->ptr;
            }
}
class node * node::deleteNode(class node * head){

        node * curNode=new node();
        node * prevNode=new node();
        int data; 
        if(head==NULL)
        cout<<"List Empty\n";
        cout<<"Enter Data to be deleted\n";
        cin>>data;
        curNode=head;
        while(curNode!=NULL){
            if(curNode->info==data){
                    if(curNode==head){   //This part where my code fails
                        head=head->ptr;
                        cout<<"val of head at:"<<head->info;
                        delete (curNode);
                        return head;                    
                    }
                    else{
                        prevNode->ptr=curNode->ptr;
                        delete(curNode);                
                        return head;    
                    }
            }
            else{
                    prevNode=curNode;           
                    curNode=curNode->ptr;
            }
    }
        cout<<"Node not found\n"    ;
        return head;

}
int main()
{
    node *head =NULL;
    node *n1=new node();
    int choice;
    while(1){
        cout<<"\n1:: Insert Node\t2:: Traversal\t3:: Delete\n";
        cout<<"Enter your Choice\n";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice){
            case 1:     head=n1->insertNode(head);
                        break;
            case 2: n1->traverseList(head);
                        break;
            case 3 :n1->deleteNode(head);
                        break;
            default: cout<<"Invalid Choice\n";
                            break;
        }           
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody help me out what i am missing

This is the snapshot of my execution
[image]

Comment: Does your code work if you delete the head before removing elements 8 and 9?

Comment: `class node *ptr;`  Side note -- there is no need to clutter the code with `class` all over the place.  Just declare the class, and once you do that, just use the name `node` instead of `class node`.

Comment: `node * newNode=new node(); node * curNode=new node();`  Why do you create two nodes to insert just one node?  Maybe the issue is this, and you're only seeing the symptoms of this when you delete.  Also, what debugging have you done?

Comment: @ Imcphers No it does  not work

Comment: @N.Nihar You make similar errors in `traverseList` here: `node * curNode=new node();`  All you need to do is `node* curNode;` and then set it to the existing node.  Otherwise you're creating a memory leak each time you call these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are shifting the `head` to `head->ptr` but you the return value (address) is not captured by you while calling the delete function.

```
case 3 :n1->deleteNode(head);
```

change it to:

```
case 3 : head = n1->deleteNode(head);
```

Comment: just in that case ,how it was working for the other cases

Comment: The problem was you were doing `head=head->ptr` but that was done locally. After the program function returns, you will see that value of head is same as it was before deleting head.

What you did was correct by return the address of new head, but you missed to change it in your main function. While in other case, since head was not change, you didn't get that problem and it worked smoothly.

If you still have some doubt, do ask.

Comment: how the value of head is same ,when am returning the new address of head?

Comment: you were returning the new address of head but the way you called the function `n1->deleteNode(head)`, you were not updating the value of head.

Answer (score 1):

There's not just the head problem here, but a memory leak as well in the deleteNode method. In the beginning of deleteNode you assign curNode and prevNode to a new node:

```
node * curNode=new node();
node * prevNode=new node();
```

Then you reassign both later on in the method without deleting this allocations you created.

Then for head not changing as expected, you can modify the address that head points to, but not change the address head points using a single pointer. You should reassign head in your main function to the value that is returned by deleteNode, or pass head to deleteNode as a double pointer so you can change the object it points to.

Comment: @N.Nihar The reason this doesn't work as expected is using single pointer vs a double pointer.

Comment: i did understood about the memory leak issue ,but i dint got the double pointer stuff

Comment: When you pass the single pointer, you're only getting the address of what head points to, not the address of head itself. So head itself that is passed into the method as a single pointer is a different copy than what is in your main method. If you use a double-pointer, then you will pass the address of head through your method, so now you can modify head what head points to, which means you can reassign the address it points to from your deleteNode method as well.